# How to get data from property list from Documents?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to the Objective-C

I want to read a file.plist from path Documents:

```
/4BC1E3AF-15AD-4F33-A55D-E52C60F13DE8/data/Containers/Data/Application/95BD9BE3-5A5A-4EAC-A9FE-133EF64D1D1A/Documents"
```

Can you help me replace this line of code?:

```
NSDictionary *dictRoot = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"TestPlist" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Full code:
[here](https://github.com/loydkim/DataFromPlist/blob/master/DataFromPlist/ViewController.m)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *subjectList;
    NSMutableArray *contentList;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    subjectList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    contentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    
    NSDictionary *dictRoot = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"TestPlist" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *arrayList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dictRoot objectForKey:@"Data"]];
    [arrayList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
             [subjectList addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Title"]];
             [contentList addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Content"]];
        }];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [subjectList count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [subjectList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [contentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;
    
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the URL of the Documents folder in the container with

```
NSURL *documentsFolderURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                             URLForDirectory: NSDocumentDirectory
                             inDomain: NSUserDomainMask
                             appropriateForURL: nil
                             create: false
                             error: nil];

NSDictionary *dictRoot = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[documentsFolderURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestPlist.plist"] error: nil];
```

There is also `dictionaryWithContentsOfURL` although I recommend to prefer `NSPropertyListSerializtion`

Comment: thanks , did not work ,Or I don't know how to replace

Comment: **What** doesn't work? This is the standard API to get the predefined directories in the container.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSURL' declares the selector 'objectForKey:'

Comment: `    NSArray *arrayList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[documentsFolderURL objectForKey:@"Data"]];
    [arrayList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
             [subjectList addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Title"]];
             [contentList addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"Content"]];
        }];`

Comment: There is no `objectForKey` in my code. Your question was to replace the line which I did. You have to read the plist with `NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL` or with `NSPropertyListSerializtion`

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying the question , Can you help me change the code for it to work?

Comment: Edit your question with that. The initial issue what how to get the correct NSURL/path. Now it's different, and the code is unreadable in comment.

Comment: See the edited answer. `documentsFolderURL`, that's for `[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"TestPlist" ofType:@"plist"]`. vadian put `dictRoot` again, so use it correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Larme , I want to read the file from path Data  no from path Bundle